# Configure glass box in AppScan standard

Tags: bluemix-app-scan

I would like to configure a glass box agent in JBoss application server.
However when l install the glass box's agent, as soon as l arrive to this section and click next.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W12p3.png)
I always have this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqdAr.png)
Thanks for your help